# No funciona @click de vue en datatables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables, vue.js

Estoy usando datatables server side de *Yajra* para Laravel y tengo lo siguiente:

```
var table = $("#dt_user_draw").DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  processing: true,
  responsive: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ordering: false,
  "ajax": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": 'url'
  },
  "columns": [{"data": "user"},
              {"data": "email"},
              {"data": "registered_at",},
              {"render": function (data, wea, row) {
                          return '<a href="" @click="showDrawUser" ><i class="nav-icon far fa-eye fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" title="Ver Draw"></i></a></li>';
                          }
              }]
  });
```

Dentro del render en la ultima columna, tengo un `@click="showDrawUser"`, el tema es que no renderiza y no funciona el click y si se inspecciona elemento aparece el `@click` y no encuentro solución a esto.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que eso pueda funcionar. Tanto DataTables como Vue parten de la base que controlan el DOM, y esas suposiciones se contradicen. Cuando DataTables inserta un elemento al DOM y trata de añadirle un listener de Vue como `@click`, a esas alturas Vue ya rendereó el DOM e interpretó los listeners. No va a escuchar directivas añadidas a mano por DataTables.

Yo te aconsejaría usar un plugin de datatables para vue. Pero para resolver tu duda puntual, lo que podrías hacer es dibujar una tabla HTML via Vue y **después** instanciar DataTables sobre ella.

Por ejemplo, en el componente:

```
export default {
  name: 'Dtt',
  data() {
    return {
      persons: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDrawUser(person) {
      console.log('showDrawUser', person);
    },
    initDtt() {
      $(document).ready(() => {
        $("#dt_user_draw").DataTable({
          "columns": [
            { "data": "user" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "registered_at" },
            { "data": "actions" }
          ]
        });
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $.ajax({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": 'url/example',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).then((res) => {
      this.persons = res.data;
      this.initDtt();
    });
  }
};
```

Lo que hace es: al montar el componente, hace un llamado, se trae la data. Esa data tiene la forma:

```
{
  "data": [{
      "user": "Tiger Nixon",
      "email": "tiger@gmail.com",
      "registered_at": "2011/04/25"
    },
    {
      "user": "Garrett Winters",
      "email": "garrett@gmail.com",
      "registered_at": "2011/07/25"
    },
    {
      "user": "Ashton Cox",
      "email": "ashton@gmail.com",
      "registered_at": "2009/01/12"
    },
    {
      "user": "Cedric Kelly",
      "email": "cedric@gmail.com",
      "registered_at": "2012/03/29"
    },
    {
      "user": "Airi Satou",
      "email": "airi@gmail.com",
      "registered_at": "2008/11/28"
    }
  ]
}
```

tú asignas `res.data` a la propiedad `persons` del componente.

En el HTML tú tienes:

```
<div class="dtt">
  <table id="dt_user_draw">
    <thead>
      <th>user</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>registered</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="person in persons">
        <td>{{person.user}}</td>
        <td>{{person.email}}</td>
        <td>{{person.registered_at}}</td>
        <td>
          <a @click="showDrawUser(person)">
            <i class="nav-icon far fa-eye fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" title="Ver Draw"></i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

De manera que, estando poblada la propiedad `persons` dibuja las filas de la tabla declarando sus listeners y **recién entonces** invocas DataTables para que haga lo mínimo: proveer paginación, sorting y búsqueda.